# Need to figure out how to make an object transparent in 2.92 or need to download 2.8

Tags: transparency

I worked on Blender a couple years back on an old laptop. I reinstalled 2.92 for my new one, and I don't know if I'm stupid or if this latest version is completely different from what I knew. Literally all I'm trying to do is make an object transparent to see my reference image through it. I edit the alpha of my basic material, I turn blending mode to Alpha Blend, and the object becomes totally see through. Even turning the alpha back to 1 doesn't make it visible again so long as I have alpha blend mode. Trying to find tutorials for how to get it the way I want, and the only ones for 2.92 bring up editing nodes? Do I really need to do that for something as simple as editing the alpha of an object so I can see through it in the viewport?

2.92 just seems pretty undocumented in general, so I had the thought of just trying to download a previous version of Blender, but any attempt to download a previous release from the site redirects me to the download page for 2.92. Are they not allowing official downloads of 2.8 versions, or is the site buggy, or what? Cuz clicking those download links has not gotten my browser to download anything.

I'm just trying to get back on the Blender bike, and now it's like I'm trying to drive a jet ski instead. Call me stupid as hell, but please tell me how I can easily make an object transparent or give me a working download link to 2.8.

Comment: Please show all your material settings, and possibly [upload your .blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: If you do decide to use an older version of Blender, all versions right back to 1.0 are available from [this link](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/).